# How do I edit an existing table with EPPlus

Tags: .net, epplus

I have an Excel worksheet with a table in a template xlsx file. I am populating the worksheet with EPPlus. How do I edit the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with the answer above. It works if the number of columns and names/ordinals of those columns have not changed, but will fail if there is a change to schema. There are a few things that need to be updated to ensure that the file is Excel compliant.

1. Set the `count` attribute on the `tableColumns` element:
2. Syncronise the column headers in your table with the column elements inside the `tableColumns` element

   ```
   var table = sheet.Tables.First();
   var tableElement = table.TableXml.DocumentElement;
   tableElement.Attributes["ref"].Value = rng.Address;
   var columnNode = tableElement["tableColumns"];
   columnNode.Attributes["count"].Value = rng.End.Column.ToString();
   for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
   {
       if(columnNode.ChildNodes.Count == i)
       {
           var clonedNode = columnNode.ChildNodes[i - 1].CloneNode(true);
           clonedNode.Attributes["id"].Value = (i + 1).ToString();
           clonedNode.Attributes["name"].Value = dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
           columnNode.AppendChild(clonedNode);
       }
       else
       {
           columnNode.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["name"].Value = dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
       }
       if(i == reportInstance.Data.Columns.Count - 1)
       {
           while(columnNode.ChildNodes.Count > reportInstance.Data.Columns.Count)
           {
                columnNode.RemoveChild(columnNode.ChildNodes[i + 1]);
           }
       }
   }

   if (tableElement["autoFilter"] != null)
   {
       tableElement["autoFilter"].Attributes["ref"].Value = rng.Address;
   }
   ```

Comment: Glad I didn't self accept my own answer. I'll review this later and mark as correct next time I use EPPlus

Comment: @JustinDearing, I added some (non tested) code to remove extra columns. The code i posted had been tested with taking a smaller table and re-sizing it to have more columns, but not taking a larger table and re-sizing it to have less columns. Needs testing, but should work. The reason i use this approach rather than clearing is because if you create the nodes using AddNode, they get XMLNS references and fail the Excel schema validation

Comment: What is reportInstance?

Answer (score 8):

[This is a clarification of a workaround methodology described on codeplex](https://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/253630).
The only way to do this is to get the range of the table body, append data to it and edit the table xml manually via the `Table.TableXml` property. In the xlsx file, which is just a zip file of xml files, each table is a separate xml document. `Table.TableXml` represents that raw xml as an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

Assuming you have an empty table in your template, with a header and no body, the following will work.

```
var table = ws.Tables["MyTable"];
var start = table.Address.Start;
var body = ws.Cells[start.Row + 1, start.Column];

var outRange = body.LoadFromDataTable(myDt, false);
// or however you wish to populate the table

var newRange =
    string.Format("{0}:{1}", start.Address, outRange.End.Address);

var tableElement = table.TableXml.DocumentElement;
tableElement.Attributes["ref"].Value = newRange;
tableElement["autoFilter"].Attributes["ref"].Value = newRange;
```

In my limited attempts to do this, this created an xlsx file that excel opened correctly without any warnings or errors.

Comment: Very good to know this, and works for me, so +1. Two caveats: (1) Be sure that your `DataTable` (or whatever `LoadFrom*` source you're using) loads exactly as many columns as the existing table has; otherwise, Excel will see corruption. You can depend on `table.Address.End` rather than `outRange.End` to avoid this. (2) `ws.Dimension` does not reflect this approach's update to the table's XML. (I'm not aware of a direct in-API way to "refresh" the sheet or package to reflect it, either.)

Comment: I have used this code and it's working fine. But, anyone knows if it's possible to automatically apply a formula to the newRange that is already set in the loaded excel file?